# Socket won't accept the strings

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

This is my code:

```
public class EchoServer {

    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream din;
    DataOutputStream dout;

    public EchoServer() 
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("server started");
            //ss = new ServerSocket(0);
            //System.out.println("listening on port: " + ss.getLocalPort());
            ss = new ServerSocket(49731);
            s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println("connected");
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            Server_chat();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EchoServer();
    }

    public void Server_chat() throws IOException {

        String str;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in ));
        do
        {
            System.out.println("enter a string");
            str = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("str " + din.readUTF());
            dout.flush();            
        }
        while(!str.equals("stop"));
    }
}
```

I verified 49731 port by passing port no. 0 earlier and got this port.

When I run the above code on Netbeans the output shows "server started" and then it keeps on running even though it should show connected and rest of the input I provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And then it keeps on running even though it should show connected and
>   rest of the input I provide.

Why it should go on printing 'connected'?

```
s=ss.accept();
```

> *In this line you are:* listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The
>   method blocks until a connection is made.

`accept` method will wait for a client that connect to him. So you need to provide a client that connect to the server. Otherwise he'll wait forever!

For some examples about how to use socket in java see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) and [here](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/).

For more about `accept()` read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept())

Comment: thanks i got it , i created another client java program and ran both of them simultaneously to achieve the desired outcome.